# T_SQL: Conversion of Date to DateTime ... error

Tags: t-sql

I am getting this error message when running one of my queries:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3 The conversion of a date data type
>   to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I started out by removing all date-comparisons in the Where clause but I am still getting the error.

Any ideas what is going on and what I should look for?

Thanks!

Comment: You did not post the offending statement.

Comment: *Here is the error I'm getting from this SQL query I'm not going to show you. Please speculate on what things might be causing the problem.* is not an acceptable question here.

Comment: based on the information you provided, here, in my expert opinion is the error:

The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @Ken White: Thanks! The Query selects numerous fields - including some Date Fields. Having never seen this error before, I don't know what IS an acceptable question here. I was hoping that someone [like Peter Smith below, perhaps] might give me a pointer.

Comment: @Irb: I'm sorry - I am attempting to FIND the offending statement . . . but it is probably something like: 'Select . . . Some_Date_Field, . . . From Some_Table'. There is nothing exotic about the Query. Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: That's not how SO works. This isn't a *make me a list of possibilities* site. If you want help, ask a **specific question**, and provide the relevant information in your question that we'll need to try to answer. If you can't be bothered to do so, perhaps this isn't the site for you to look for help.

Comment: @Ken White: Move on to a question that you CAN help with.

Comment: Valid close reasons include failure to provide a MCVE, which in the case of your query would be the table schemas and SQL involved. You don't get to choose what you need to provide; nor do you get to choose who can comment, answer, or vote on your questions. If you're unclear about that, see the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more I can only guess, however, the likely cause is related to either `NULL` values or out of range values. The different `date` and `datetime` data types have different date ranges. For example `date` has a range 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31 but `datetime` has the range 1753-01-01 through 9999-12-31.

Comment: Thanks! I was not thinking of VALUES in the DB possibly causing the error. I appreciate your help. I will try & do a Cast/Convert on the Date Fields [to varchar] and see what I get back. I appreciate your willingness to attempt some possible reasons for the error - and sorry I was not more informative with my original question.

Comment: Thanks for your input - it hit the nail on the head. One of my date fields defined [using Convert(DateTime, ProblemDateField, 121)] was getting Date data fed into it and therefore throwing the error. I changed that to Convert(Date, ProblemDateField, 121). Now that I understand the problem - it seems so elementary. Thank you so much for helping even though I provided so little information. Your answer was exactly what I needed to resolve my issue.